# How to check if URL is external link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to check in razor view, if the URL adress is EXTERNAL link. Web local URLs are: http://test.web.tt and http://localhtost. I want to open all external links in new window.

External link is a link out from the site to another web....

Example:
http://test.web.tt/about .. local
http://localhtost/about .. local
The two above links are both local (the same page on the site, on the same host, only different URL - DNS name)

Thanks

Comment: Define external! Is this everything not being on your PC? Or anything from outside your network? Or from outside your home?

Comment: Your edit does not make it any clearer. What is "another web"? You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and in particular this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get meaningful help. How should an app determine that `http://test.web.tt` is in "the same web" as `http://localhost`?

Comment: So you mean `localhost` and `test.web.tt` refer to the same host-computer?

Comment: Ok sorry, I have one page on the same server, with  two URL which link to identical content. I think tahat is clear that I only need determine links that simply not refer to the same site but out from the site, to another different web no-matter where another web is (network or etc), simply another website. My apologize, I thought that my quesetion is clear and simple. I think that @Sandip Jaiswal answered the question... I will test it and mark as answer. I wrote that: The two above links are both local (the same page on the site, only different URL)..

Comment: so yes the same server, the same computer tha same IP only DNS name is different locahost and test.web are the same web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(Request.IsLocal)
 {
      //do whatever you want here
 }
```

You just need to check IsLocal property of current request.

Please mark as answer if I helped.